# open new tab in iTerm and execute command there

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I have found way to open new tab in `iTerm`:

```
newtabi()
{
    osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm" to keystroke "t" using command down'
}
```

And I want to execute some commands in new tab. Let it be simple command `pwd`. How to do it?

If I run ...

```
newtabi && pwd
```

The new tab is opened as expected, but `pwd` command is executed not in new tab but in old one, where I typed `newtabi && pwd`

I use `zsh`. My os is `OS X 10.8.5`

Comment: That question is 8 years old and the accepted answer is far from ideal. I still hope to see passing some arguments to `open -a iTerm` to run a command.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `tell session -1 of current terminal to write text "pwd"`:

```
activate application "iTerm"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
tell application "iTerm" to tell session -1 of current terminal to write text "pwd"
```

Comment: if opened more than one `iTerms`, it opens new tab in correct `iTerm` instance, but writes `pwd` in last tab of first instance of iTerm

Comment: @efr You're right. I edited the answer to change `terminal 1` to `current terminal`. Now it should run the command in the current window instead of the window that was opened first.

Comment: This did not work on mac 10.11.6 with iTerm2. In script editor, "Unexpected end of line but found identifier" and "terminal" is highlighted

Comment: This no longer works on macOS 10.14: `execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed to send keystrokes. (1002)`

Comment: @KernelSanders You need to allow iterm to access System event by checking iTerm in MacOS Settings -> Security -> Accessibility

Answer (score 21):

As of at least macos Mojave, iTerm 3.2.8, if you run:

```
$ open -a iTerm .
```

It will add it as a tab to the current window.

Comment: can you then execute commands in the new terminal with this?

Comment: worked for me for iTerm with zsh

Comment: Any ways to also pass the command to execute?

Comment: @sorin Yes, if you pass a path to a binary as the final argument (instead of `.` in the answer), it will execute it (after a confirmation prompt from iTerm)

Comment: Thank you!  When I'm willing to create a new tab (sometimes I want a separate window), this is far and away the easiest solution.  It avoids having to deal with an idiosyncratic scripting language.  (Applescript is supposed to be easy and intuitive, but the fact that it is not like any commonly used language makes it non-intuitive.)

Comment: is it possible to split the existing tab this way?

Answer (score 20):

```
osascript \
-e 'tell application "iTerm" to activate' \
-e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm" to keystroke "t" using command down' \
-e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm" to keystroke "ls"' \
-e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTerm" to key code 52'
```

Comment: I'm getting `148:156: syntax error: Expected end of line but found identifier. (-2741)` on this.

Comment: what is `key code 52` supposed to do?

Answer (score 18):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to work. I also wanted to pass multiple commands. This is what I came up with.

```
newtabi(){  
  osascript \
    -e 'tell application "iTerm2" to tell current window to set newWindow to (create tab with default profile)'\
    -e "tell application \"iTerm2\" to tell current session of newWindow to write text \"${@}\""
}
```

Example usage

```bsh
newtabi pwd
newtabi 'cd ~/ && pwd'
newtabi 'echo \"Hello New Tab\"'
```

For more complex actions, I would recommend breaking up the commands.

```bsh
code_folder="/path/to/code"

alias project="cd ${code_folder}/my-project/foo && yarn run start"
```

Then, `newtabi project`

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can pass my current `pwd` to make the command look like: `newtabi '$PWD/foo && yarn run start'?

Comment: @Raj, good question. I personally break up the commands into more consumable aliases and/or functions. I added another example. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Raj `newtabi "$(pwd)/foo && yarn run start"`

Comment: this is the best answer, should be top-rated

Comment: I find it works better to use `write text \"$*\"` instead of `${@}`. It lets you do `newtabi cmd arg1 ...` without having to use single quotes around the cmd and its arg. For args that contain spaces, you have to use the awkward syntax `newtabi cmd '\"arg with space\"'`. But with the original `${@}` I couldn't get args with spaces to work at all. Commands with quotes don't work in either case.

Answer (score 2):

[`ttab`](https://github.com/mklement0/ttab) is a *macOS and Linux CLI for opening a new terminal tab/window, optionally with a command to execute and/or display settings*

From its samples:

```
# Open a new tab, execute a command, wait for a keypress, and exit.
ttab 'ls "$HOME/Library/Application Support"; echo Press a key to exit.; read -rsn 1; exit'
```

Comment: This is easily the best option!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are searching for JXA version:

###### Reusable class

```js
class iTerm {
  constructor() {
    this.app = Application("iTerm");
    this.window = this.app.currentWindow();
  }
  findOrCreateTab(tabName, command) {
    this.app.activate();
    let existingTab = this.findTab(tabName);
    if (existingTab == undefined) {
      existingTab = this.createTab(tabName);
      console.log(`Created new tab: ${tabName}`);
      existingTab.currentSession().write({ text: command });
    } else {
      existingTab.select();
      console.log(`Found existing tab: ${tabName}`);
    }
    return existingTab;
  }
  createTab(name) {
    const newTab = this.window.createTabWithDefaultProfile();
    const session = newTab.currentSession();
    session.name = name;
    // console.log(newTab.index());
    // console.log(newSession.name());
    // console.log(newSession.profileName());
    return newTab;
  }
  findTab(name) {
    const tabs = this.window.tabs();
    for (const tab of tabs) {
      let session = tab.currentSession();
      // Strange, but iTerm uses `profileName` instead of `name` for keeping manually assigned session name.
      const tabName = session.profileName();
      if (tabName === name) {
        return tab;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

In case you are also interesting how to use ESM modules in JXA (via browserify), then here is a good example: https://github.com/johnelm/node-jxa. Plus https://www.npmjs.com/package/esmify.

After setting up you can import reusable class as show below:

```js
import iTerm from "../lib/iTerm";

const app = new iTerm();
app.findOrCreateTab("MyTab", `cd "$HOME"`);
```